# Performing a deep object search and expanding all the values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, search

I need to search for a value in a object graph and when the value is found set the expanded property to true on that object and the containing objects up the object graph.

So with a the data:

```
`regions: [
{ id: 1, name: 'Canada Mock', code: 'CA', bulk: '', expanded: false, subRegions: [] },
{ id: 2, name: 'Mexico', code: 'MX', bulk: '', expanded: false, subRegions: [] },
{
  id: 2, name: 'United States region', code: 'US', bulk: '', expanded: false, subRegions: [
    {
      id: 1, name: 'US sub region', countries: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', code:'SV', states:[]},
        {id: 2, name: 'Trinidad and Tobago', code:'TR', states:[]},
        {
          id: 3, name: 'United States', code:'US', states: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Alabama', code: 'AL', expanded: false, cities: [] },
            { id: 2, name: 'Alaska', code: 'AK', expanded: false, cities: [] },
            { id: 3, name: 'Arkansas', code: 'AR', expanded: false, cities: [] },
            { id: 4, name: 'Arizona', code: 'AZ', expanded: false, cities: [] },
            { id: 5, name: 'Delaware', code: 'DE', expanded: false, cities: [
              { id: 1, name: 'Towson', code: 'TOW', expanded: false, airports: [] },
              { id: 2, name: 'Viola', code: 'VIO', expanded: false, airports: [] },
              { id: 3, name: 'Wilmington', code: 'WIL', expanded: false, airports: [] },
            ] },
            { id: 6, name: 'New York', code: 'NY', expanded: false, cities: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Albany', code: 'ALB', expanded: false, airports: [] },
                { id: 2, name: 'Binghamton', code: 'ALB', expanded: false, airports: [] },
                { id: 3, name: 'Buffalo', code: 'ALB', expanded: false, airports: [] },
                {
                  id: 4, name: 'New York City', code: 'NYC', expanded: false, airports: [
                    { id: 1, name: 'Newark Liberty International', officialName: 'Newark', code:'EWR', airportType: 'Airport', lat: 0, long: 0 },
                    { id: 2, name: 'LaGuardia', officialName: 'LaGuardia', airportType: 'Airport', code:'LGA', lat: 0, long: 0 },
                    { id: 3, name: 'JFK', officialName: 'JFK', airportType: 'Airport', code:'JFK', lat: 0, long: 0 }
                  ]
                },
                { id: 5, name: 'Syracus', code: 'SYR', expanded: false, airports: [] }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]`
```

and a search for LGA the following path would be expanded 'United States region'->'US sub region'->'United States'->'New York'->'New York City'

Comment: Where's your code ? What did you try so far ?

Comment: I didn't want to limit the solution to what I had come up with as I was hoping for a better solution

Comment: That one's easy, isn't it :)

Comment: Plus, it's not clear what you expect. LGA is for LaGuardia airport I presume, but LGA is not in your data set. Do you want to search by name ? Code ?

Comment: And do you expect the search to work only with airport or also with intermediate level (regions, subregions, countries ...). For example if we search `Alabama` what should happen ? Please be more specific

Comment: I changed the data so that it has the LGA code.  I was expecting to search by code but name search would be possible to. I was expecting to search over any potential level. I only know the code I'm searching for and that it will match an object in the graph

Comment: Use recursion. Your problem can be rephrased like this: a node must be expanded if it matches the search, or if any of its children must be expanded. Just translate that in code, and you have your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out for myself:

```
findNode(value){
  this.expandIfNeeded(this.details, value, ["regions", "subRegions","countries","states","cities","airports"])
}

expandIfNeeded(node, value:string, childProperyNames:string[]){
  if(node.code === value){
     node.expanded = true;
     return true;
  }
  let found:boolean = false
  let childName = childProperyNames[0];
  let subNode = node[childName];
  if(subNode)
    subNode.forEach(element => {
      if(this.expandIfNeeded(element, value, childProperyNames.slice(1)))
      {
        node.expanded = true;
        found = true;
      }

  })
  return found;
}
```